# Simple SqlCommand - Very High CPU

Tags: c#, sql-server

I made a simple Console Application. (Code below).

When I run the program on my computer, it works fine. However, when I run it on our server (Windows Server 2008) which is a virtual machine, after a minute of so, the process takes all the CPU. It goes to 100% usage until I close the application.. The only difference I can think of would be that the database on my computer is local and on the server, the database used is on another machine..

Any idea what could cause the CPU to go crazy...?

```
static void Usings()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT GETDATE()", conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString());

        dr.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I modified the code to only open a SqlConnection and I still get the behaviour.

I also added some code to get notified on the Garbage Collector Approach. The CPU goes to the top milliseconds before I receive the notification. So I suspect the garbage collector to be responsible for this. Any clue? Suggestion where I could dig deeper?

New code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Register for Garbage Collector Notifications
        GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(10, 10);

        // Start a thread using WaitForFullGCProc.
        Thread thWaitForFullGC = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WaitForFullGCProc));
        thWaitForFullGC.Start();
        #endregion

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT GETDATE()", conn))
            { }
        }

        _sw.Start();

        Log("Waits for key press...");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

PS: If I do not open the SQL Connection, CPU stays stable (0%)....

When the program starts...
[image]

After exactly 3 minutes 11 seconds and some ms...

[image]

Comment: What do you mean after a minute? That should only take ms to execute. Are you running it in a loop? If not does the datetime ever get displayed on the console?

Comment: Which process is pegging the CPU? Yours, or SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith, Yes the datetime gets displayed... After a minute because of the Console.ReadKey(). I know this program makes no sense.. I isolated a simple SqlCommand to troubleshoot this issue.. I was having the issue in another large application.

Comment: @Blorgbeard my process.

Comment: Have you managed to determine the time internal between each line of code? This would enable you to isolate the code fragment which takes the most time out of the total execution time.

Comment: This is very strange. Is this code the absolute minimum required to repro? Like, if you remove the `ExecuteReader` stuff, does the problem go away?

Comment: @fujiFX The program goes to the Console.ReadKey() instantly.. It's just that after some delay (about a minute).. The CPU goes nut... Can't figure out what is going on...

Comment: Maybe the garbage collector.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I did not try this out. I will give this a try

Comment: Why aren't you using the `using` syntax for your other disposable objects?

Comment: @C1sc0 Yes it looks like the GC... See my update.

Comment: @Blorgbeard.. Please see my update